# Yii 2. Не грузятся ресурсы в мобильной версии

Tags: yii2, yii

Всем доброго дня. Вопрос немного не конкретный. Есть сайт на yii-2, при проверке в https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly, постоянно какие то ошибки, то картинки не грузятся, то сторонние ресурсы, то css или js. Постоянно ошибки разные, бывает что их вообще нет. При открытии сайта на мобильном проблем никаких нет. Вопрос общий, хотелось бы услышать какие то мысли, или совет на что обратить внимание.[image: результат проверки search.google.com]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Обратитесь в проблемным ресурсам прямо из браузера напрямую. Посмотрите выводятся ли они. Исправьте файл `robots.txt` чтобы он позволял поисковым роботам индексировать файлы. Проверьте, что нет блокировки в файлах с правами доступа (например `.htaccess`) по IP-адресам, вдруг Ваш IP разрешен (поэтому у Вас и нет ошибок), а для других стоит запрет. Проверьте нет ли запретов на тоже самое на стороне провайдера (зайдите на сайт через другого провайдера, VPN, proxy).